# c++ - an iterator for an abstract class

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I have an abstract class, for example a class the represents a geometrical shape. I will have concrete classes inheriting from `Shape`, such as a rectangle and a triangle.

I would like to iterate over the points (another class) a shape is composed of, so `Shape` must supply an interface for it.
The iteration should be in this manner:

```
for(Point p : shapeObject){ ... some code}
```

But I don't want the `Shape` class to determine for the child class what containers to use. For example, a rectangle will have a `std::array<Point, 4>` container while a triangle will have a `std::array<Point, 3>` container.

So my question here is, what is the most elegant C++ way to do this?

Comment: You can take a look at (or outright use) [`any_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html) and `any_iterator` from Boost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to solve the "problem"<sup>*</sup> in the particular case where the points are stored in containers supporting random access iteration (such as `std::array` or `std::vector` is to use plain pointers as iterators:

```
struct Point {};

struct Shape
{
    typedef Point* iterator;
    typedef const Point* const_iterator;
    virtual iterator begin() = 0;
    virtual const_iterator begin() const = 0;
    virtual iterator end() = 0;
    virtual const_iterator end() const = 0;
    virtual ~Shape() {}
};
```

And have the derived classes implement `begin()`, `end()` using pointers to the first and past the end elements of the array they hold.

Alternatively, you could use type-erasure with e.g. [boost.any_range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html) or via an `any_iterator` type. This may be beyond the scope of this answer but [here is a good article on precisely this problem](http://thbecker.net/free_software_utilities/type_erasure_for_cpp_iterators/any_iterator.html).

---

<sup>* That is assuming there really is a problem that requires hiding the type of the iterators. Note that you can also write template code to deal with different iterator types.</sup>