# ISO C++ input iterator with an abstract class as the value type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[*`Cpp17InputIterator`*](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/input.iterators#tab:iterator.input.requirements) requires `reference` to be convertible to `T`, which is an object type.

What if `T` is an abstract class? Does it mean that `T*` does not meet the requirements of being an iterator? This seems inconsistent with introduction of input iterators in [[iterator.requirements.general]/1](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements.general#1).

Note this is a question about rules in the current standard draft. I'm aware of questions about how to code like in [c++ - an iterator for an abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463756/c-an-iterator-for-an-abstract-class). (Actually the original question is met when implementing some variant of `any_iterator`.)

**EDIT**: Suggested by comments, I find [LWG 484](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue484) covering the case. I still wonder if there is a more specific entry targeting the question, and the status of the proposal/resolution.

Comment: This requirement seems more constraining than the one formalized [by concepts](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements#iterator.traits-2.). Maybe the use of *share a common reference with* in place of *is convertible to* is not yet propagated to the vestigial parts of the standard?

Comment: @Oliv It seems the concept `InputIterator` in [the Range TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0896r0.pdf) does not have the similar requirement. Otherwise, I'm not clear about recent progress on rewording of these requirements. Could you show me some more reference (like DR or editorial issues) about the change?

Comment: No! And I will visit back this Q/A to see if a committee member or a very passionate up-to-date coder answer you!

Comment: See [N2624](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2624.pdf) and [LWG 2962](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2962).

Comment: @xskxzr Thanks, though N2624 seems outdated. This should be actually a case of [LWG 484](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue484), although as per [LWG 2962](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2962), it can have a separated entry. It seems there is no dedicated one. Is there any necessity to send a new issue?

Comment: @FrankHB N2624 made the first change from "convertible to T" to "convertible to const T&". I don't think a new issue is needed because it is already fixed in Range TS.

Comment: The issues about std-discussion isn't the question and shouldn't be written in it (neither is it on-topic). You may put it in comments if you feel compelled to do so, but note that comments are temporary in nature and may eventually be deleted.